# how to hide the guest list / attendees to see other attendees in create calendar event using outlook api

Tags: node.js, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-api

In create calendar event through outlook api how to hide the attendees to see other attendees.

I want attendees other than the organizer not to see who the event's attendees are, i checked the entire api documentation but cant find how to hide the attendees to see each other.

Please let me know if i want to pass any additional parameter in the api request inorder to fullfill my requirement.

Below is my sample request

```
            {
              'Start': {
                'DateTime': new Date(date),
                'TimeZone': 'Asia/Calcutta',
              },
              'End': {
                'DateTime': new Date(date),
                'TimeZone': 'Asia/Calcutta',
              },
              "ShowAs": "Free",
              "IsReminderOn":true,
              "Importance": "High",
              "Organizer" :{EmailAddress:{"Address":"{email}","Name":"{name}","Type": "Required"}}
              "Attendees" :[{EmailAddress:{"Address":"{attendee1email}","Name":"{attendee1emailname}"}},{EmailAddress:{"Address":"{attendee1emailemail}","Name":"{attendee1email2name}"}}]
            }
```

based on above sample create event request, how should i hide attendee1 should not see attendee2 as a guest and viceversa, but organizer should be able to see both the attendees.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Outlook. The only way to achieve this would be to create separate events for each attendee.

Comment: actually we have seperate events currently but wanted to merge those events into one to reduce the complexity. And by the way google calendar api have an option to hide the guest list by sending a property  called "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests" when sent as false guests cannot see other guests. similary option i was looking for outlook api create calendar event.

Comment: This isn't an API limitation, it's a limitation of Exchange/Outlook. You should give this feedback to those product groups. You can submit feedback from the Help menu in Outlook or https://outlook.office.com.